# Program to sort numbers not in descending order

Tags: c

I have written a program to sort numbers in ascending order.

I successfully compiled and executed it, but the problem is that at first 'for' loop its taking one more input than than the entered.

Suppose if I enter a value of `t` equal to 5 , then below loop takes 6 inputs.

```
for(i=0;i<t;i++){
    scanf("%d\n",&a[i]);
}
```

I debugged this code, and observed that `i=0` is taking 2 inputs, but how do I solve it.

**Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int t,i;
    printf("Enter the number of numbers:");
    scanf("%d",&t);
    int a[t],temp;
    printf("Enter the numbers\n");
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d\n",&a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<t-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<t;j++)
        {
            if(a[i]>a[j])
            {
                temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Sorted\n");
    for(int k=0;k<t;k++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",a[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d\n",` --> `scanf("%d",`

Comment: Further the loop will take 5 inputs not 6 as you thought.

Comment: @irshadjm No, that would make it even worse.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` syntax for integer is as follows:

```
int i;
scanf("%d", &i);
```

It does not need `\n` like in `printf`

Change your for loop into this

```
for(i=0; i<t; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you are printing into your screen the symbol "\n" , it means that the outputstream takes a command to change line. This is being used only in the printing process. When you are trying to input values via scanf its actually useless and problematic thus breaking your code. So you have to write:

`scanf(" %d", &a[i]);`